# Uniform convergence of $\sin^2(x+1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

$g_n(x)=\sin^2(x+1/n)$, $f_n(x)=\int_0^x g_n(t)\,\text dt$, where $x\in[0,\infty)$. Question is whether $f_n(x)$ is converges uniformly on $[0, \infty )$? 
Clearly this question has been answered here but I really can't get that hint properly.

What I only guess that $g_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $\sin^2(x)$, and also know that if $g_n(x)$ would convergent uniformly to $\sin^2(x)$,  then $\int_a^b g_n(t)\,\text dt$ converges to $\int_a^b \sin^2(t)\,\text dt$ where $a, b\in\mathbb R$. But I'm confused whether $g_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent or not and here limit of the  integration isn't finite.

Please help me to answer it in the answer section. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$|g_n(x)-g(x)| \leq \frac 2 n$ by MVT, so $g_n \to g$ uniformly. For $f_n$ the best thing to do is to evaluate the integral. $f_n(x)=\int_0^{x} \frac  1 2(1-\cos 2(t+\frac 1 n))dt=\frac x 2 -\frac 1 4 \sin (2(x+\frac 1 n)$. Similarly $f(x)=\frac x 2 -\frac 1 4 \sin (2x)$. it is now easy to see (by MVT again) that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $[0\infty)$.

Comment: sir I can't understand from the first line and the last conclusion how you use MVT?

Comment: @DebprasadKundu $|(\sin^{2}(x))'|=2|\sin x \cos x| \leq 2$.

Comment: @DebprasadKundu If $|g'(x)| \leq 2$ then $|g(x+\frac1  n)-g(x)| =\frac  1 n |g'(\xi)| \leq \frac 2 n$ where $\xi $ is some number between $x$ and $x +\frac 1 n$.